# ElasticSearch fsriver plugin not updating index

Tags: elasticsearch

I installed Elastic Search (1.4.4), mapper-attachement(2.4.3) and fsriver(1.4.0) in my windows system.

I executed below query to index a file from location c:\tmp2

```
PUT _river/newRiver/_meta
{
    "type": "fs",
    "fs": {
        "url": "c:\\tmp2",
        "update_rate": "1m",
        "includes": "*.txt",
        "excludes": "resume"
    },
    "index": {
        "index": "docs",
        "type": "doc",
        "bulk_size": 50
    }
}
```

But the index is getting created without any data. It's not updating the index.
In the elasticsearch console the following error appears 
`update_mapping [index_event] (dynamic)`. 
and then no more messages in the console.

Please help me to solve this issue.
Let me know If I am missing any settings.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us the content of your c:\tmp2 folder and what do you see when running `curl -XGET localhost:9200/docs`? Also maybe it's  good idea to [enable debug mode](https://github.com/dadoonet/fsriver#debug-mode) by adding `fr.pilato.elasticsearch.river.fs: TRACE` to your `$ES_HOME/config/logging.yml` file.

Comment: The file name mail.txt contain following string :- 

 The xml file related to test cases are not parsed beacuse of Java version issue.
 From Jenkins log we got following details